# Handling with python packges in new docker user

Tags: python, docker, pip

I am trying to understand how to handle python packages with the non-root user in docker.

Let me explain how I handle user permissions: when running docker container I run it with -e USER_ID=$UID, on the entrypoint I create a new user with that user id, so when running the container it will run with the same permissions of the original user. I read about it at:
https://denibertovic.com/posts/handling-permissions-with-docker-volumes/

About python packages: I know the best practice for pip is to the user --user so the packages will be installed on ".local". the problem is that I run pip install on the Dockerfile itself, meaning before I changed the user (I'm still on root). so the python packages installed on the ".local" of the root user. when changing to the new user on the entrypoint I can no longer access to the ".local" and losses all of my installed python packages

I have thought about giving the new user permissions to /root/.local directory, but I am not sure that this is the best solution

How can I switch to the new user with the same UID of the original user, and use the python packages I have installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `pip install` as root, without the `--user` option, and without an active virtual environment.

One of the things you want to get out of running containers as a non-root user is that, in the unlikely event of a security issue, a compromise can't modify your application code.  So the code should be owned by a different user than the runtime user of the application.  In a Docker context the easiest way to do this is to install your application as root, then run as non-root.

A near-universal Dockerfile can look like

```sh
# Basic setup
FROM python:3.7
WORKDIR /app
# (We are root by default.)

# Install dependencies (globally, within the image).
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install requirements.txt

# Copy the application in.
COPY . .

# Set up our runtime user.
RUN useradd -r app
USER app

# Specify the default command to run.
CMD ["/app/myapp"]
```

Docker is pretty inconvenient as a development environment.  I'd suggest setting up an ordinary Python virtual environment for your day-to-day work (your local system probably even already has Python installed) and reaching for Docker mostly as a deployment mechanism.  Trying to mount your application code into a container gives you a weird hybrid environment where on the one hand "local" development requires root access and a rather complex environment, and on the other your container environment isn't actually what you're building from your Dockerfile and running in production.